# how to setup a password screen in my android application?

Tags: java, android

i'm creating a personal android application.

this application should be private. so i should create a password screen that only user can access to application.

in my setting Activity there is a Switch Widget that when user Enable it (and set password for it) , i wanna show password screen before my MainActivity then user Enter Password to go to MainActivity.
and when user Disable it i wanna Just show MainActivity when my app runs.

How should i do it?

tnx for giving any help an suggestion for my  problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the EnterPassword activity be the first to open when the app starts using this code on your Manifeft:

```
<activity android:name=".EnterPasswordActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Remember to take off the intent filter from your MainActivity.

And in your EnterPasswordActivity you check if is enable or not. If it's not:
`startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));`

You could use SharedPreferences to make enabled or not. :)

Answer (score 0):

So simple just on start screen use set condition if user enable switch widget and enter password match it some constant or hard code password then show switch screen else go on main screen as in example

```
if(isSwitchEnable() || password=="12345"){

                    launchActivity(PasswordActivity.class);

        }else {

                    launchActivity(MainActivty.class);

        }
```

Comment: launch activity is function in which you intent to go next activity

Answer (score 0):

as I know, you can set [Doalog](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) with costum view in your onCreate method of MainActivity before set contentview and by given answer from this Dialog(true or false password) you can permit to user for seeing the mainlayout. 
 here is a simple code of Dialog for you:

```
final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(mContext);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_for_share);  //design your own layout for Dialog
dialog.setCancelable(false);
Button b1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
EditText input = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.input);
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     // set some codes
   }
});


dialog.show();
```